# Is there an argument to change font size for printing Notepad trough Shell Command?

Tags: shell, notepad, proficy

I have a script in Proficy - Cimplicity (Basic Script Engine) that build up a temporary text file then print it and then delete it afterward. It always worked fine, but since this script is now on an Windows 10 environment, the font is too big. Therefore, I need to change the font size of the print.

I print the text file with a shell command through notepad.

I tried to find any argument to change this, but I found nothing.

I tried changing the default size font in the Notepad application but it does not seem to affect the printing I do with the script.

```
PrinterName = """" & item$(strconfig(0),2) & """"
PrinterFile =  """C:\CIMPLICITY\HMI\projects\Error_Files\PointPrinter.Log""" 
ID=Shell("notepad /pt " & PrinterFile & " " & PrinterName)
```

I do not know the actual size of the font that prints, but I guess it's around 11. Anything smaller would be great, the goal is for it to fit in one page as it used to be in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default font size of Notepad in its registry does work on other computer.
It would appear that the first computer i was trying it on had some setting that came in conflict with the default font setting of notepad.

Also, there is no way to pass argument of any font setting trough a .txt file. Need to go with .rtf or .pdf or .html